# css property “will-change” reduce performance?

Tags: html, css

In MDN it says:

> The will-change CSS property hints to browsers how an element is expected to change. Browsers may set up optimizations before an element is actually changed.

However consider performance record:

[before adding will-change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw1sS.png)

[after adding will-change to ".innerBlock"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P47vm.png)

The rending time increased and the painting time decreased, and apparently frame rate decreased. Why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .center {
            position: absolute;
            /* margin: auto; */
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            /* top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px; */
            outline: orangered 2px solid;
            pointer-events: none;
            will-change: transform;
        }

        .block {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: orange;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            will-change: transform;
        }

        .innerBlock {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            will-change: top, left;
        }

        @keyframes drawC {
            0% {
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                /* transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px); */
            }

            25% {
                left: calc(100% - 100px);
                top: 0px;
                /* transform: translateX(100px) translateY(0px); */
            }

            50% {
                left: calc(100% - 100px);
                top: calc(100% - 100px);
                /* transform: translateX(100px) translateY(calc(100px)); */
            }

            75% {
                left: 0px;
                top: calc(100% - 100px);
                /* transform: translateX(0px) translateY(100px); */
            }

            100% {
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                /* transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px); */
            }
        }

        @keyframes drawB {
            0% {
                /* left: 0px;
                top: 0px; */
                transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
            }

            25% {
                /* left: calc(100% - 200px);
                top: 0px; */
                transform: translateX(100px) translateY(0px);
            }

            50% {
                /* left: calc(100% - 200px);
                top: calc(100% - 200px); */
                transform: translateX(100px) translateY(calc(100px));
            }

            75% {
                /* left: 0px;
                top: calc(100% - 200px); */
                transform: translateX(0px) translateY(100px);
            }

            100% {
                /* left: 0px;
                top: 0px; */
                transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
            }
        }

        @keyframes draw {
            0% {
                /* left: 0px;
                top: 0px; */
                transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
            }

            25% {
                /* left: calc(100% - 300px);
                top: 0px; */
                transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 300px)) translateY(0px);
            }

            50% {
                /* left: calc(100% - 300px);
                top: calc(100% - 300px); */
                transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 300px)) translateY(calc(100vh - 300px));
            }

            75% {
                /* left: 0px;
                top: calc(100% - 300px); */
                transform: translateX(0px) translateY(calc(100vh - 300px));
            }

            100% {
                /* left: 0px;
                top: 0px; */
                transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    const ele = document.body
    const draw = (time) => {
        const template = document.createElement("template");
        template.innerHTML = `<div class="center" style="animation: draw ${time}s linear infinite">
            <div class="block " style="animation: drawB ${time/5}s linear infinite">
                <div class="innerBlock" style="animation: drawC ${time/10}s linear infinite">contained</div>
            </div>
        </div>`
        return template.content.firstChild;
    }
    let time = 10;
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while (++time < 500) {
        fragment.appendChild(draw(time));
    }
    ele.appendChild(fragment);
</script>
```

Comment: It also says: _**Don't apply will-change to too many elements:** Don't apply will-change to too many elements. The browser already tries as hard as it can to optimize everything. Some of the stronger optimizations that are likely to be tied to will-change end up using a lot of a machine’s resources, and when overused like this can cause the page to slow down or consume a lot of resources._

Comment: And: _**Don't apply will-change to elements to perform premature optimization**. If your page is performing well, don't add the will-change property to elements just to wring out a little more speed. will-change is intended to be used as something of a last resort, in order to try to deal with existing performance problems. It should not be used to anticipate performance problems. Excessive use of will-change will result in excessive memory use and will cause more complex rendering to occur as the browser attempts to prepare for the possible change. This will lead to worse performance._

Comment: Thanks, but could u explain a bit about it's mechanism?

Comment: You can read more [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-will-change/#will-change)